# How to replace a list of words with a string and keep the formatting in python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list containing the lines of a file.

```
list1[0]="this is the first line"
list2[1]="this is the second line"
```

I also have a string.

```
example="TTTTTTTaaaaaaaaaabcccddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffff"
```

I want to replace list[0] with the string (example). However I want to keep the word length. For example the new list1[0] should be `"TTTT TT TTa aaaaa aaaa"`. The only solution I could come up with was to turn the string example into a list and use a for loop to read letter by letter from the string list into the original list.

```
for line in open(input, 'r'):
        list1[i] = listString[i]
        i=i+1
```

However this does not work from what I understand because Python strings are immutable? What's a good way for a beginner to approach this problem?

Comment: lst = list(string) turns the string into a list, and converts an immutable object to a mutable one. You can convert it back to a string with ''.join(lst). You can also just solve this by using for x in range(start, end, step).

Comment: is it possible that the replacement text will be shorter than the original string?

Comment: Its a strange one. The replacement text is actually a string of all the characters from the file which I read into List1. Except I have stripped newlines and spaces and sorted the characters. So it should be the exact same amount of characters except for the missing spaces and newlines.

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably do something like:

```
orig = "this is the first line"
repl = "TTTTTTTaaaaaaaaaabcccddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffff"

def replace(orig, repl):
    r = iter(repl)
    result = ''.join([' ' if ch.isspace() else next(r) for ch in orig])
    return result
```

If `repl` could be shorter than `orig`, consider `r = itertools.cycle(repl)`

This works by creating an iterator out of the replacement string, then iterating over the *original* string, keeping the spaces, but using the next character from the replacement string instead of any non-space characters.

The other approach you could take would be to note the indexes of the spaces in one pass through `orig`, then insert them at those indexes in a pass of `repl` and return a slice of the result

```
def replace(orig, repl):
    spaces = [idx for idx,ch in enumerate(orig) if ch.isspace()]
    repl = list(repl)
    for idx in spaces:
        repl.insert(idx, " ")
        # add a space before that index
    return ''.join(repl[:len(orig)])
```

However I couldn't imagine the second approach to be any faster, is certain to be less memory-efficient, and I don't find it easier to read (in fact I find it HARDER to read!) It also don't have a simple workaround if `repl` is shorter than `orig` (I guess you could do `repl *= 2` but that's uglier than sin and still doesn't guarantee it'll work)